# How do I scale in a layer style overlay greater than 150% in Photoshop while using the timeline?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I was wondering how or why is there a hard limit to 150% scaling for any layer overlay that's available as I thought this could be anything over 1% in theory. Or is there a trick to get around this?

Surely with the hardware available, this shouldn't be related to that.

See attached of what I'm referring.

**EDIT**
My overall goal here is to animate the style and keyframe the scale. The answer by Luciano was ok for a different application but unfortunately, this doesn't work with the timeline AFAIK.

**Using Photoshop 2020.**

[image]

Comment: There're a lot of hard limitations like this in Photoshop: my best guess is Adobe is full of sadists. I don't know if it's possible to make scale of the layer style more than 150%, but creating a shape with a gradient, clipping it and then scaling would be my workaround

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Can you expand on that as an answer and I'll mark it as a solution seeing as there's no way to do this via the native method? Yes, quite the sadists...!

Comment: better than trying to figure out _why_ is Photoshop like this, could you tell us _what_ are you trying to achieve? Perhaps there are other solutions that don't involve scaling a gradient overlay at all.

Comment: The more you scale it, the more you lost the colors at the borders. You can always edit the gradient removing or softening those colors instead.

Comment: *Luciano*. I'm simply wanting to scale more than 150%. *eoNas*, I'm aware of that but not the solution I was after. I was hoping to animate this in the timeline and you can animate styles but not what Luciano suggested. I'll update the question to point this out.

Comment: I insist: if you share more details about the effect you're trying to create we could come up with a solution. Your question is still vague. What is the animation going to look like? If you're just trying to scale a Layer style by more than 150%, you can't.

Comment: The animation how it looks is pretty much irrelevant as I cannot do what I want. It's pretty hard for me to show you when I cannot do the thing I'm supposed to show you. I cannot be more descriptive. The effect wanted is simply as stated. **Scaling a layer style beyond 150%.**

Answer (score 0):

- Create a vector shape (<kbd>U</kbd>) - it could be any shape, if it's going to be larger than the artboard or the layer below;
- Change the Fill to a gradient, keep **Align with Layer** checked;
- Transform (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and scale the shape to the size you want;
- clip it to the layer below by holding <kbd>ALT</kbd> and clicking between the layer thumbnails;
- change opacity / blending mode / etc if necessary.

Comment: Thanks but this cannot be animated whereas styles can. I'll update the question with this.

Comment: Transformations can be animated.

Comment: Basic transformations can (Position of the layer), there's no key value for the shape fill as far as I can see. I've googled this also but cannot find anything.